# Environment variables “leak” into Docker container action. Why? How to prevent?

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions

Imagine, you have have a custom third-party Docker container action implemented with Java. This actions uses `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to run it’s logic. Think about Gradle application plugin which creates and executable Java application that relies on that environment variable. Imagine this Docker container action is based on `openjdk:17`.

This action is really simple, it prints the environment and JDK location:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "Environment:"
printenv

printf "\n"
echo "JAVA_HOME:"
printenv JAVA_HOME

printf "\n"
echo "Java location:"
command -v java

printf "\n"
echo "Java version:"
java --version
```

If you just run this custom action, it would work:

```yaml
- uses: madhead/actions-env-leak@main
```

The output would be:

```
JAVA_HOME:
/usr/java/openjdk-17

Java location:
/usr/java/openjdk-17/bin/java
```

Everything is fine.

Now, imagine your workflow also needs Java, but a different version:

```yaml
- uses: actions/setup-java@v2
  with:
    distribution: 'adopt'
    java-version: '11'
```

Now, if you run the custom action again, it is screwed up:

```
JAVA_HOME:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/11.0.11-9/x64

Java location:
/usr/java/openjdk-17/bin/java
```

Notice that `JAVA_HOME` now points to a wrong location! This variable just leaked from the workflow! Now, if the custom action relies on it to run the Java application, it would fail, because this path is not valid inside the container!

This is what actually happened with one of my actions. The issue is [discussed here](https://github.com/madhead/read-java-properties/issues/28) and [here](https://github.community/t/environment-variables-leak-into-docker-container-action-why-how-to-prevent/218458). Actually, I didn't get any responses on the GH forum, which is strange for me as the issue could be very annoying and potentially this is a bug.

I have created a minimal reproducible example [here](https://github.com/madhead/actions-env-leak).

Why do the variables leak? Why is this behavior implicit? Shouldn’t it be explicit? The workflow author may want to override some of the variables, but if should not be the default, shouldn’t it? Can action or workflow authors prevent this leakage from happening right now?

Comment: Did you find a solution that you can update here?

Comment: Just found this issue you created which contains a response from Github's support https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25738#discussioncomment-3249001